# Find Sum of Maximum for each category through lambda expression?

Tags: lambda, java-8

We have Stream of Scores object like-

```
<Scores>
    <score match_option="any" row_label="A" column_label="1" scoreValue="4"/>
    <score match_option="any" row_label="A" column_label="2" scoreValue="3"/>
    <score match_option="any" row_label="A" column_label="3" scoreValue="2"/>
    <score match_option="any" row_label="A" column_label="4" scoreValue="6"/>
    <score match_option="any" row_label="A" column_label="N/A" scoreValue="1"/>
    <score match_option="any" row_label="B" column_label="1" scoreValue="3"/>
    <score match_option="any" row_label="B" column_label="2" scoreValue="4"/>
    <score match_option="any" row_label="B" column_label="3" scoreValue="1"/>
    <score match_option="any" row_label="B" column_label="4"/>
    <score match_option="any" row_label="B" column_label="N/A" scoreValue="2"/>
</Scores>
```

How can I get Sum of maximum for each category(i.e. row_level), For e.g. For above example-
Sum = Maximum for category A(6) + Maximum for category B(4) = 10

Comment: What is your try?

Comment: I am trying Something like-  scores.stream().filter(e -> e.getColumnLabel().equalsIgnoreCase("N/A"))
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Score::getRowLabel,
                            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Score::getScoreValue))));

Comment: Just want to ensure if score_value is not present for any of Score, It should compare it with 0 instead of NullPointerException.

Comment: What you posted isn't a stream of scores. It's an XML document. So there must be some code you already have to turn this into a `Stream<Score>`. Write the business logic of turning non present `scoreValue` to 0 there. Also what does it mean to have two `scoreValue` for the same score?

Comment: You should put what you have written in comments into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your score is represented as follows:

```
class Score {
    private String matchOption;
    private String rowLabel;
    private String columnLabel;
    private Integer scoreValue;

    public Score(String matchOption, String rowLabel, String columnLabel, Integer scoreValue) {
        this.matchOption = matchOption;
        this.rowLabel = rowLabel;
        this.columnLabel = columnLabel;
        this.scoreValue = scoreValue;
    }

    public String getMatchOption() {
        return matchOption;
    }

    public String getRowLabel() {
        return rowLabel;
    }

    public String getColumnLabel() {
        return columnLabel;
    }

    public Integer getScoreValue() {
        return scoreValue;
    }
}
```

You were already on the right track with the groupingBy collector. Just map null values to 0 inside `Comparator.comparing()`:

```
 Map<String, Optional<Score>> maxScores = scores.stream()
    .filter(e -> !e.getColumnLabel().equalsIgnoreCase("N/A"))
    .collect(
             Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Score::getRowLabel,
                    Collectors.maxBy(
                            Comparator.comparing(
                                    s -> s.getScoreValue() == null ? 0 : s.getScoreValue()
                            )
                    )
            ));
```

And finally getting the sum of the maximums can be done as follows:

```
int sumMaxs = maxScores.values()
        .stream()
        .map(s -> s.map(Score::getScoreValue).orElse(0))
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .sum();
```